# How to save ArrayList data into Firebase using Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have some problem when I try to save array data from an Android Kotlin to Firebase Database.

I want to save data as shown below:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cjgu.png)

but, when I saved the data, in the Firebase database it always updated the "pemasukan" object, not creating new data.

the stored data is always like the picture below
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPzu.png)

Anyone can help me please.
Sorry for my English ;)

This is the code I am using for

```
class PemasukanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 private lateinit var database : FirebaseDatabase
 private lateinit var mRef : DatabaseReference
 lateinit var currentDate : String
 private val id_user = "agus"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pemasukan)

        btnSimpan()
}
//aksi tombol untuk simpan data
private fun btnSimpan(){
    btn_simpan_pemasukan.setOnClickListener {
        val pemasukan = Pemasukan()
        if (edt_nama_barang.length() > 3){
            pemasukan.keterangan = edt_nama_barang.text.toString()
        } else {
            edt_nama_barang.error ="Nama Barang Harus lebih dari 3 huruf"
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        if (edt_jumlah.length() > 3){
            var jumlah = edt_jumlah.text.toString()
            pemasukan.jumlah = jumlah.toLong()
        }else{
            edt_jumlah.error ="Jumlah Harus lebih dari 3 huruf"
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        simpanData(pemasukan)
    }
}

//simpan data ke firebase
private fun simpanData(listPemasukan :Pemasukan){
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("ddMyyyy")
    currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
    val data = Dataitem()
    data.id = currentDate
    data.user_id = id_user
    val nameList = ArrayList<Pemasukan>(Arrays.asList(listPemasukan))
    data.pemasukan = nameList
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    mRef = database.getReference("pendataan")
    mRef.child("${currentDate}").setValue(data)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success . .", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            edt_nama_barang.text.clear()
            edt_jumlah.text.clear()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal Input Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            it.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("FIREBASE_ERROR", it.message)
        }

}
```

And the POJO class like this:

```
    data class Dataitem (
    var id : String = "",
    var user_id : String = "",
    var pemasukan : ArrayList<Pemasukan>? = null,
    var pengeluaran : ArrayList<Pengeluaran>? = null
  )
data class Pengeluaran (var jumlah : Long = 0,
                        var keterangan : String = "")
data class Pemasukan (var jumlah : Long = 0,
                      var keterangan : String ="")
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using for this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i was updated my code. Help me please ;)